# $F(2n-1) = F(n-1)^2 + F(n)^2$, where $F(i) $ is the $i$'th Fibonacci number, for all natural numbers greater than $1$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm proceeding by induction, but I have no idea how to do the inductive step. The Fibonacci sequence takes on the definition:
$F(0)=0$
$F(1) = 1$
$F(2) = 1$

So far, my proof is as follows:

Base Case:
$F(2) = 1 = F(1)^2 + F(0)^2$. This case holds

Inductive Step: We assume the claim holds for $n$ and show it holds for $n+1$...

$F(2n+1) = F(2n)+F(2n-1)=F(2n) + F(n-1)^2+F(n)^2$

I am stuck on how to reduce this expression to $F(n)^2 + F(n+1)^2$...

Edit: Thank you for the responses. I realize I made an egregious error in defining the fibonacci sequence. I have corrected it to the definition we use in my class.

Edit by DS : Now changed the indexing to the standard convention of the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 2):

We need a second part to our inductive hypothesis
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{2n-1}=F_{n-1}^2+ F_n^2 \\
F_{2n}=F_{n}(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1})
\end{eqnarray*}
To prove the first equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{2n+1}=F_{2n}+F_{2n-1}= F_{n}(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}) + F_{n-1}^2+ F_n^2 \\= F_{n-1}(F_{n-1}+F_n)+F_n^2+F_nF_{n+1}= F_{n+1}^2+F_{n}^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
To prove the second equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{2n+2}=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}=  F_{n+1}^2+F_{n}^2+F_{n}(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}) \\ =F_{n+1}(F_{n+1}+F_{n})+F_{n}(F_{n}+F_{n-1})= F_{n+1}(F_{n+2}+F_{n}).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It seems we're using the second equation in our proof of the first equation, which we then use to prove the second equation. Isn't that circular?

Comment: It's fine, Donal Splutterwit assumes by induction that both identities are true up to $n$ and with that proves the identity for $F_{2n+2}$, so he can proceed to use that and finish the induction step :)

Comment: There are two layers to the induction but it is not circular. 
$X_n \text{ and } Y_n \Rightarrow X_{n+1}$ and $Y_n \text{ and } X_{n+1} \Rightarrow Y_{n+1}$

Comment: If $F_0=0$ as usual, then $F_{n}^2+F_{n-1}^2$ equals $F_{2n\color{red}{-1}}$, not $F_{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you Donald, I see how the reasoning works now. And yes Jack, I made a bad mistake, it is corrected now :)

Comment: @HisokaMoroh You need to change the title of your question to  $F(2n-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach. By setting $M=\small\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ we have
$$ \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+2} \\ F_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = M \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} \\ F_{n}\end{pmatrix},\qquad M^n=\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_n\\ F_{n} & F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix} $$
and $F_{2n+1}$ is the top-left element of $M^{2n}=(M^n)^2$, where
$$ \begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_n\\ F_{n} & F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2} & F_n(F_{n-1}+F_{n+1})\\ F_n(F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}) & F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2\end{pmatrix} $$
leads to
$$ F_{2n+1}=F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2,\qquad \boxed{F_{2n\color{red}{-1}}=F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2.}$$

---

By Binet's explicit formula we have $F_{2n}=F_n L_n$, where Lucas numbers $L_n$ are defined through $L_0=2,L_1=1$ and $L_{n+2}=L_{n+1}+L_n$.

Comment: Righty o Jack. I have edited the question & my solution to the standard convention. $ \ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

The key idea is to prove a more general statement. With the initial statement, we can see that odd Fibonacci numbers seem to be quite annoying to work with.

The hypothesis is
$$ F_n = F_{n-k}F_k + F_{n-k-1}F_{k-1} $$
for well-chosen $k$ (You can work out the details.). Now this identity is easy to prove via induction and we can plug in $n = 2k$ to get the result.