# Prove for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory

Define $$b_n $$ by $$b_1 = 1$$ and $$b_n = a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}$$ for $n>2$ , where $$a_n$$ is the $n$ th Fibonacci number.

Prove that $$a_{2n} = {a_n}{b_n}$$

I have tried induction in the question but I am unable get to an answer.

I have tried $a_{2n+2} = {a_n}{a_{n+1}} + {a_n}{a_{n-1}} + a_{2n+1}$

Comment: I'm sorry... what?  You may want to read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have edited it now. Actually, I am not versed in MathJax language.

Comment: Hi Krushna, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? This is not a forum where people just do your HW for you. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144

Comment: what the value of $b_2$? inst the segond part of definition of b aplies to n > 1?

Comment: use induction, and always show your process(no matter even if they are wrong) otherwise your question won't get views and you'll be downvoted

Comment: This can just be stated as proving a formula for $F_{2n}$. See the bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form

Comment: Hint: use the fact that a_{2n+1} = a_{n+1}^2 + a_{n}^2 in your induction hypothesis

Comment: Can you prove that a_{2n+1} = a_{n+1}^2 + a_{n}^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*in this answer, I’ll write $F_n$ and $F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$ instead of $a_n$ and $b_n$, respectively, as that’s more intuitive*

**Use induction:**

First of all, it’s clear that $F_2\cdot(F_1+F_3)=1\cdot(1+2)=3=F_4$.

Now assume that $F_{2n}=F_n\cdot(F_{n-1}+F_{n+1})$.

Then
$$F_{2n+2}=F_{2n}+F_{2n+1}$$
$$=(F_n\cdot F_{n-1}+F_n\cdot F_{n+1})+(F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2)$$
$$=F_n\cdot F_{n-1}+F_n\cdot F_{n+1}+F_n\cdot(F_{n+1}-F_{n-1})+F_{n+1}\cdot(F_{n+2}-F_n)$$
$$=F_n\cdot F_{n+1} + F_{n+1}\cdot F_{n+2}$$

***Note:*** here we use the fact that $F_{2n+1}=F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2$. In case you didn’t know that, it already has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484884/f2n-1-fn-12-fn2-where-fi-is-the-ith-fibonacci-number-for).

Answer (score -1):

## Use Binet's Formula for the nth Fibonacci number

Refer [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html)